# Error with a quadrant giving function

Tags: function, haskell, guard-statement

I tried to make a function to give the quadrant name when inputting the x and y coordinates. However, I am getting the error: 
"parse error on input ‘=’

Failed, modules loaded: none."

I tried adding a "|otherwise.." but that still didn't work. I made sure i covered all the possiblities of x and y.

```
data Quadrants = Origin |
                 Quadrant_I | Quadrant_II | Quadrant_III | Quadrant_IV |
                 X_Axis_Positive | X_Axis_Negative | Y_Axis_Positive | Y_Axis_Negative
  deriving (Show, Eq)
quadrant :: Float -> Float -> Quadrants
quadrant x y
    |x>0 && y>0 = Quadrant_I
    |x<0 && y>0 = Quadrant_II
    |x<0 && y<0 = Quadrant_III
    |x>0 && y<0 = Quadrant_IV
    |x=0 && y=0 = Origin
    |x>0 && y=0 = X_Axis_Positive
    |x<0 && y=0 = X_Axis_Negative
    |x=0 && y>0 = Y_Axis_Positive
    |x=0 && y<0 = Y_Axis_Negative
```

Answer (score 4):

```
x=0
```

`=` is used as a [keyword for definitions](https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords#.3D). Since you cannot (and don't want to) define `x` to be `0` at this point, you get a parsing error. What you're looking for is the comparison function. In Haskell, this is `==`, see [`Data.Eq`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Eq.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simplify the structure if you decouple sign of each coordinate as another type and pattern match on the intermediary type, i.e.

```
data Sign = Negative | Zero | Positive
sign x | x==0 = Zero
       | x>0  = Positive
       | otherwise = Negative
```

and then

```
quadrant :: Float -> Float -> Quadrants
quadrant x y = go (sign x) (sign y)
       where go Zero Zero = Origin
                Zero Positive = Y_Axis_Positive
                ...
```

Or you may eliminate the need of the Quadrants type and instead you can use the tuple (Sign, Sign) which may be more useful for next steps.

Comment: You can just use `compare 0` in place of `sign`, and pattern match on the resulting `Ordering` values.

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly a duplicate of karakfa's very good answer, just to point out that Haskell comes with a data type that is isomorphic to `Sign`, namely `Ordering`.

```
quadrant :: Float -> Float -> Quadrants
quadrant x y = go (compare x 0) (compare 0 y)
               where go EQ EQ = Origin
                     go EQ GT = Y_Axis_Positive
                     go EQ LT = Y_Axis_Negative
            ...
```

---

Your `Quadrants` type is just isomorphic to pairs of `Ordering` values, which means you could write code like

```
type Quadrant = (Ordering, Ordering)
origin = (EQ, EQ)
quadrant_i = (GT, GT)
-- etc

quadrant :: Float -> Float -> Quadrant
quadrant x y = ((compare x 0), (compare y 0))
```

This has the drawback of requiring a language extension to pattern match against, say, `origin` rather than `(EQ, EQ)` directly.